# Convert and sum variable a, grouping by variable b

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to convert the variable ar66 from nvarchar to numeric and sum it for the variable ar5.

I create the following code, but it does not work:

```
select top(10) ar5, (
select 
  case 
     when isnumeric(q1.ar66) = 1 then 
          cast(q1.ar66 AS numeric)
     else
          NULL
  end
AS 'ar66_numeric'
from rmb_loan q1)
from rmb_loan q2
group by q2.ar5
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the problem that you have?

Comment: Your subquery is not correlated to the outer query - meaning every row will have the same summed value (assuming the conversion worked). It is unlikely that is your goal. And for future reference, statements like "does not work" are not helpful. How do you know it does not work? Does it generate an error? If so, post the complete error message. No one can see your screen or read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select top (10) ar5, sum(try_convert(numeric(38, 6), q1.ar66))
from rmb_loan q2
group by q2.ar5;
```

When using `select top` you should normally have an `order by` clause.

Comment: I get this error message: 'numeric' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @AndreaB . . . Oops, the type needs to be the first argument.